Can the elliptic curve $E/K$ be regarded as a $K$-vector space?
Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.
My question is: Can $E(K)$, the group of $K$-rational points, be regarded as a $K$-vector space?
If $E(K)$ has torsion, it cannot be considered a $K$-vector space because $K$-vector spaces do not have torsion. However, what can we say about the case when $E(K)$ has no torsion?
Thank you for your help.

No. For example if $K$ is a number field then $E(K)$ is finitely generated, so even if it's torsion-free it's a free abelian group of some rank, so has no $K$-vector space structure (unless it's trivial).

The object $E(K)$ is an abelian group, a $\Bbb Z$-module. Assume the no-tosion-case. So a "parallel" question is, extracting only this information, We have a $\Bbb Z$-module with no torsion. Can we organize it as a vector space over some field of characteristic zero? Maybe in a canonical way?! If so, than we have at least an induced structure of a $\Bbb Q$-vector space, so we have divisibility. (In a more or less canonical manner.) But in our case - let us go back to it - to insure divisibility a lot of division polynomials for the curves need to be considered. So $K$ must be "big"...

But then, operations beyond "complex or real multiplication" are needed to have a $K$-vectorspace...
